# Not able to switch to 3rd Party play store app activity for the second time launch through Appium script

Tags: android, automation, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

**Problem:**

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error occurred while starting App. Original error: 'com.tohsoft.applock.ui.unlockapp.StartupActivity' never started (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

**Scenario:** 
Whenever I tried to run Appium script for own project with below the activity switching for a scenario. only first the 3rd party app activity launched successfully but later getting an error as above.

```
    String appPackage="com.tohsoft.applock"; 
    String appActivity="com.tohsoft.applock.ui.unlockapp.StartupActivity";

    Activity activity = new Activity(appPackage, appActivity);
    activity.setStopApp(false);
    ((AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>) driver).startActivity(activity);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    AndroidElement appLockLogo = driver.findElementById("com.tohsoft.applock:id/img_scaled_image_view");
```

Comment: FYI, Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
{appActivity: com.phonepe.app.ui.activity..., appPackage: com.phonepe.app, autoGrantPermissions: true, deviceName: Moto G4 Plus, platformName: android, platformVersion: 7.0}, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 7.0, takesScreenshot: true, webStorageEnabled: false}